# Send request from one docker container to another

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, docker

I'm trying to move some existing servers to be housed within docker containers. I have two: an app server and an api server but developed with node.js. I have them both working within an ubuntu vm and can hit both apps from outside the vm which is great.

Each server has it's own domain. The app server uses the domain **app** and the api server uses the **api** domain, clever I know. Locally I added both domains to my hosts file to point to the ip assigned to the ubuntu vm.

The only issue I'm having is there is a request sent from the app server that needs to be routed to the api server. Tried editing the hosts file of both the app server container (via the Dockerfile) and the ubuntu vm however the request fails.

Is there a simple way to get that request to not go out and try to resolve the **api** domain but get it to point to the api container?

Answer (score 3):

A typical solution to this would be to use Docker's `--link` option to link the containers.  That is, if you do:

```
docker run -d --name api myapi
docker run -d --name app --link api:api myapp
```

Then within the `app` container, the hostname `api` will map to the `api` container.  You will also have a set of environment variables available that describe the exposed ports on the linked container.  E.g., if your "api" container exposed port 80, the variable would look like:

```
API_PORT_80_TCP=tcp://172.17.0.10:80
API_PORT_80_TCP_PORT=80
API_PORT_80_TCP_PROTO=tcp
API_PORT=tcp://172.17.0.10:80
API_NAME=/app/api
API_PORT_80_TCP_ADDR=172.17.0.10
```

There are some disadvantages to the link option:

- This only works for containers hosted on the same physical host
- If you restart the "api" container, you have to restart the "app" container, too.

Both of these particular problems can probably be resolved by the orchestration tool of your choice if you are operating in a multi-host environment.

Comment: **Environment variables are no longer the recommended method for connecting to linked services.**

Comment: *(Environment variables will only be populated if you’re using the legacy version 1 Compose file format)*
Instead, use the link name (by default, the name of the linked service) as the hostname to connect to.
https://docs.docker.com/compose/link-env-deprecated/

Comment: **--link is a legacy feature.** 
You should always prefer using Docker network drivers over linking.

Comment: Well, *now* it is :)

Answer (score 0):

**The linking feature *(--link)* is a legacy feature.**

**You should always prefer using Docker network drivers over linking.**

**Example**: running a Redis container with Redis binding to localhost then running the redis-cli command and connecting to the Redis server over the localhost interface.

```
$ docker run -d --name redis example/redis --bind 127.0.0.1
$ # use the redis container's network stack to access localhost
$ docker run --rm -it --network container:redis example/redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1
```

See the docs for details.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/link-env-deprecated/

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings